# In War, what if one player runs out of cards mid-war?

Tags: war-card-game

In war, if two people play the same card they go to war and have to stake multiple cards on the next play. If another person and I go to war, but the opponent only has one card left (can't stake enough cards) then how is the game supposed to proceed? Should the opponent place down their last card? And should I still put down three cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers vary. From [pagat.com](https://www.pagat.com/war/war.html):

> Most descriptions of War are not clear about what happens if a player runs out of cards during a war. There are at least two possibilities:
>
> 1. If you don't have enough cards to complete the war, you lose. If neither player has enough cards, the one who runs out first loses. If both run out simultaneously, it's a draw. Example: Players A and B both play sevens, so there is a war. Each player plays a card face down, but this is player B's last card. Player A wins, since player B does not have enough cards to fight the war.
> 2. If you run out of cards during a war, your last card is turned face up and is used for all battles in that war. If this happens to both players in a war and their last cards are equal, the game is a draw. Example: Players A and B both play sevens, so there is a war. Player A plays a card face down, but player B has only one card, so it must be played face up. It is a queen. Player A plays a card face up and it is also a queen, so the war must continue. Player B's queen stays (B's last card) while player A plays a card face down and one face up, which is a nine. Player B wins the war and takes all these seven cards (the five cards that A played and the two cards that B played) and the game continues normally.

Comment: The way I always played was that the player who had enough cards had to supply the stakes for the player who had run out. Further increasing the never-endingness of the game.

Answer (score -2):

Actually the right way to play is that if someone doesn’t have enough cards to fulfill the war, the other person should match the player with fewer cards. If there is only one card left for one person, both players flip over just one card to be equal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).